# Managing nested json in cascading drop downs (in angular)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

**The problem**

I am trying to manage some select lists that are populated by a large nested json string. I will try to explain this as clearly as possible -

There are 5 levels (all nested within each other in the json) that can branch out. The highest level is populated in the first drop down, and the lowest in the last.

When the user lands on he page, only the top most level is populated with the most parent level items in the json. Upon selecting this item, the 4 drop downs below would then populate with all of the sub items (corresponding with parent child level). Each time you select a drop down in order from top to bottom, it would then refine the drop downs below based on the selection, all the way down to the 4th select, which would then boil the 5th item down to 1 sub array based on the previous choces - kind of like -

```
parent[choice1].parent[choice2].parent[choice3].parent[choice4].child; (if that makes sense)
```

**My attempt**

Based off this here is what I tried in angular. I basically set up the first drop down to populate upon arrival and then set on change functions for each level selector that would change the ones below accordingly. Here's what that looks like (warning - it's messy).

```
$scope.scope1Change = function() {
        //clear arrays for fresh use
        $scope.array3.length = 0;
        $scope.array4.length = 0;
        $scope.array5.length = 0;

        $scope.array2 = $scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas;

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas, function(index) {
            angular.forEach(index.sections , function(indx){
                $scope.array3.push(indx);
            });
        });

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas, function(tex) {
            angular.forEach(tex.sections , function(texi){
                angular.forEach(texi.lessons , function(texa){  
                    $scope.array4.push(texa);       
                });
            });
        });

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas, function(tex) {
            angular.forEach(tex.sections , function(texi){
                angular.forEach(texi.lessons , function(texa){
                    angular.forEach(texa.skills , function(texo){
                        $scope.array5.push(texo);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };

    //function for level 3 (2 has changed)
    $scope.scope2Change = function() {
        //clean arrays

    $scope.array4.length = 0;
    $scope.array5.length = 0;

    $scope.array3 = $scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections;

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections, function(tex) {

            angular.forEach(tex.lessons , function(texi){

                    $scope.array4.push(texi);

            });
        });

angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections, function(tex) {

            angular.forEach(tex.lessons , function(texi){
                angular.forEach(texi.skills , function(texo){
                    $scope.array5.push(texo);
                });
            });
        });

    };

    //function for level 4 (3 has changed)
    $scope.scope3Change = function() {
        $scope.array5.length = 0;
        $scope.array4 = $scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections[$scope.array3.indexOf($scope.scope3)].lessons;

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections[$scope.array3.indexOf($scope.scope3)].lessons, function(tex) {
            angular.forEach(tex.skills , function(texi){
                $scope.array5.push(texi);
            });
        });
    };

    //function for level 5 (4 has changed)
    $scope.scope4Change = function() {
        $scope.array5 = $scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)].areas[$scope.array2.indexOf($scope.scope2)].sections[$scope.array3.indexOf($scope.scope3)].lessons[$scope.array4.indexOf($scope.scope4)].skills;
    };
```

This works fine for 1 click through all the way down, but is having issues when you change the top most level and then try to re search downward (the bottom are coming back blank). I believe this is because each time I am setting the length= 0, but I'm honestly not positive about it.

**My concerns**

I have 2 concerns with this.

1 is the looping within looping - I feel like there must be a better way, this doesn't seem like the nicest way to do it, but it is all I could think of for this scenario, and I'm not sure how to search for an answer like this.

2 - If I am receiving the JSON in 1 big chunk, would there be a better way to handle this in general. I was trying to avoid having to make an $http request each time I request a level, so I would much prefer to keep receiving the big ol' json and have angular read through it for me. I have no idea what this does to performance on my end, I assumed it wouldn't be to bad.

Those concerns aside, this method only seems to be working when i land and go through the drop downs top down once. if I change the highest level to another one then back, then try to select down again, the bottom 2 are coming back blank. Even when I just select the highest level again, the bottom most one is blank, and should not be. I believe I am overlooking something here, but overall I would like to see if there is another way besides nesting loops within loops (this may be part of the problem).

Any/all insight would be very much appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read.

**EDIT** : I made a plunker for some clarity here - http://plnkr.co/edit/4snKCMaty9ZFl6pWLkjU?p=preview

**EDIT 2** please ignore the schema in the plunker, it's fake data for the sole purpose of testing  - It's just there so you can start on default scope and move downwards from there.

Comment: Wow, your data model is hard to understand.  What exact output are you looking for?  It seems like sometimes you'll have a scope, sometimes a lesson, sometimes a section and sometimes a skill

Comment: Appologies @JasonGoemaat, the json i created is just for testing, it out quickly, there will always be flushed out levels of everything except lessons. There may not be lessons on some levels. I am just using default scope to check, and swapping between the scopes to reset.

Comment: What about the example 'skill 9', the path to get there is `scope->area->section->lesson->skill->lesson`.  Do you want to be able to get the value at any stage?

Comment: oh wow sorry, I just copied in something real fast to get it to work. it's suppose to be scope > area> section > lesson > skill. that's it.